# What's the difference between a goal and a 'must'

Tags: word-choice

This is hard
I am setting goals for the year but some speakers call them 'musts'
Does this mean that you cannot prioritise musts like you do with goals as a 'must' MUST be done which makes them all same priority

Comment: Which *must* will you do first?

Comment: A "must" (where the word is used as a noun) means whatever the speaker thinks it means.  Most people would interpret it as something with a high priority, but how high is impossible to say, absent context (and perhaps a peek inside the speaker's head).

Comment: Taken literally, a _must_ is an existential necessity: A supply of oxygen is a must for our underwater explorations. A goal is, in contrast, an objective, whether major or minor: Finding a sunken Spanish galleon is a goal of our underwater explorations. But as Hot Licks indicates, people often characterize goals, intentions, preferences, or even idle wishes as _musts_, thereby creating a broad class of _musts_ that need not be.

Answer (score 1):

If something is a "must" it is something that should not be overlooked or missed. If something is a goal, it is something that you are aiming to achieve.

The difference in meaning would depend on your context.

In your situation, there is no difference between a *must* and a *goal*.

From a corpus linguistics perspective, the word "must" is informal, commonly used with the phrasing "*a must*". Here is some data:

[image]

Interestingly, other variations "must see" and "must have" declined in usage. It appears only "a must" is the only result that produces an increasing curve.

Searching OED:

> informal
>
> Something that should not be overlooked or missed:
> ‘this video is a must for everyone’